# Saas file is not compiling

Tags: javascript, html, css, saas, saaskit

I am trying to compile a saas file by a css file but is does not compile.  I am writing css inside saas file  but it does not show any output changes but if i put the css inside style.css its working properly. I think conneection between css and saas file is not distingushed. SO is there anyone who could help me to sort out my problems? So that if I made any css property inside saas file it will be compiled and will show the changes.

```
below is the code for map:

 {
        "version": 3,
        "file": "main.css",
        "sources": [
            "../../src/sass/main.scss"
        ],
        "names": [],
        "mappings": "AAAA,AAAA,KAAK,AAAC,CACF,eAAe,CAAA,QAAC,CAChB,aAAa,CAAA,
                     KAAC,CACd,WAAW,CAAA,KAAC,CACZ,iBAAiB,CAAA,
                     KAAC,CAClB,cAAc,CAAA,QAAC,CAClB,AAED,AAAA,CAAC"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the import. You need to import your **sass** file into your **style.css** . You can do the import inside style.css as a first line like this:

```
@import "../path/path/main.sass";
```